# Get Google Static Map of current position?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to make a homepage on my mobile website where a google map of my current position stays in the background while icons float over it. The only way to do this is to use a static image of the map, but I can't figure out a way to pull out a static map of my current position. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that's "the only way" to do what you want.  But if you want to get a static map of your current position, you can do the following:

1. Get position with `navigator.geolocation` (available on newer web browsers)
2. Construct static map url with returned coordinates
3. Use static map image somewhere on your site.

Here is code (run by `<body onLoad="setBgMap()">`) which will set a page's background image to a map of your current position:

```
function handler(location) {
    var ll, url;
    ll = [location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude].join(',');
    url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + ll + "&markers=" + ll + "&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false";
    document.body.background = url;
}   
function setBgMap() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handler);
}
```